# Character rigging challenge

Tags: animation, mesh, armature, blender-internal-render-engine

I am a newbie to blender and have been asked to do character rigging in blender. I have tried several times during the last 5 days but unfortunately, there is something wrong and I hope that someone could help.

The target is to generate a dataset consists of set of images taken for a moving 3D character.

what I have done are

1-  Created a mesh using MakeHuman, imported it into blender and put it in T-pose.
[image: MakeHuman model in T-pose]

2- Replaced the default armature in order to add another provided reference armature.
    2.1 - deleted the default armature
[image: Character after removing the armature]

2.2 - imported the refernce bvh file that contains a skeleton, roughly aligned the joints of the skeleton with the makehuman mesh and made the armature the parent of the mesh.
[image: Armature replacement]

3- Tested the created model.
[image: after parenting with auto weights]

4- Everything is working fine inside blender, I have applied an animation and it works well.

5- After that I have exported the vertices, bones and labels for the data generation task. We will apply different animations on the character and taking photos while moving. The results are ghostly images and I have been debugging for 5 days and I couldn't fix it till now. What may be wrong in the previous steps ? Is there anything that I should take into consideration before exporting the mesh files ?
[image: Buggy image in T-pose]
[image: Buggy image while moving]

all the used files in the task are attached on the following link

https://www.dropbox.com/s/um02ejnu25nghm6/files.zip?dl=0

Comment: You usually parent the mesh to the armature. If everything is working inside blender then the problem is in export script, import script, or how you handle the data in your app..

Comment: Yes @Jerryno you have pointed me to the right track, I was not supposed to apply any operation on the armature. Instead, I should edit the mesh only as the data generation algorithm was accustomed to suite the reference armature.